# jquery multiple http get requests with promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm trying to get multiple images from server using jquery get.

```
 $.each(result.Data.Files, function (i, v) {

        $.get('/mobile/image?path=' + v, function (res) {

            if (res.Success) {
                $('#images-container').append(`<img alt="Image Title" src="${res.Image}">`);
            }
        });

    });
```

After i append all images i want to call a jquery plugin to handle these images.

How can i do that using promise ?

i tries something like :

```
     $.when(
            $.each(result.Data.Files, function (i, v) {
                $.get('/mobile/image?path=' + v);
            })
        ).then(function () {

            $("#images-container").image_plugin();

            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

                let src = arguments[i];
                console.log(src)
            }



        });
```

but what i'm getting in the **then** section is just the urls and not the actual base64 response

 thanks

Comment: `$.each()` does not return anything.  So your `$.when()` is acting upon nothing.  Use `map()` instead and return the promises created by `$.get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
var defs = [];

//create Deferred for each item in array and push to defs array
$.each(result.Data.Files, function () {
    defs.push($.Deferred());
});

$.when.apply($, defs).then( function(v){
    //runs when all deferred are resolved
    $("#images-container").image_plugin(); 
    console.log(v)
});

$.each(result.Data.Files, function (i, v) {
     $.get('/mobile/image?path=' + v, function (res) {
        if (res.Success) {
            $('#images-container').append(`<img alt="Image Title" src="${res.Image}">`);
            defs[i].resolve(res.Image);
            //resolve i'th deferred
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: defs[]=$.Deferred(); this line throws an exception. what did you mean there?

Comment: Oops ..too much php today..fixed it